# is my implementation of builder violates mutability

Tags: java, optimization, mutability

I'd like to know whether my implementation of QuestionBuilder violates mutability.

```
public class Question<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {

    private QuestionHolder<T> questionHolder;

    private Question(QuestionHolder<T> questionHolder) {
        this.questionHolder = questionHolder;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return questionHolder.id;
    }

    public int getOrder() {
        return questionHolder.order;
    }

    public QuestionType getType() {
        return questionHolder.type;
    }

    public boolean isImmediate() {
        return questionHolder.immediate;
    }

    public boolean isMandatory() {
        return questionHolder.mandatory;
    }

    public List<T> getSelectedValues() {
        return questionHolder.selectedValues;
    }

    public List<T> getPossibleValues() {
        return questionHolder.possibleValues;
    }

    private static final class QuestionHolder<T extends Serializable> {

        private String id;

        private int order = 0;

        private QuestionType type;

        private boolean immediate;

        private boolean mandatory;

        private List<T> selectedValues;

        private List<T> possibleValues;
    }

    public static final class QuestionBuilder<T extends Serializable> implements Builder<Question<T>> {

        private QuestionHolder<T> questionHolder;

        public QuestionBuilder(String id) {
            questionHolder = new QuestionHolder<>();
            questionHolder.id = id;
        }

        public QuestionBuilder withOrder(int order) {
            questionHolder.order = order;
            return this;
        }

        public QuestionBuilder withType(QuestionType questionType) {
            questionHolder.type = questionType;
            return this;
        }

        public QuestionBuilder withImmediate(boolean immediate) {
            questionHolder.immediate = immediate;
            return this;
        }

        public QuestionBuilder withMandatory(boolean mandatory) {
            questionHolder.mandatory = mandatory;
            return this;
        }

        public QuestionBuilder withSelectedValues(List<T> selectedValues) {
            questionHolder.selectedValues = selectedValues;
            return this;
        }

        public QuestionBuilder withPossibleValues(List<T> possibleValues) {
            questionHolder.possibleValues = possibleValues;
            return this;
        }

        public Question<T> build() {
            Question<T> question = new Question<>(questionHolder);
            questionHolder = null;
            return question;
        }

    }

}
```

Or what should I adjust in order to resolve mutability issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: what mutability issue you are seeing?

Comment: I don't see. I am just asking because I am not sure.

Comment: then why you are having doubt on "mutability issue" if you don't think you have any?... I don't get what you are trying to ask.  At least be clear on the "mutability issue" you are trying to ask

Comment: Well basically I have trouble because I am not sure whether class well designed

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you are mutating the QuestionHolder with each builder call.
What I would do is:

1) Make all properties inside QuestionHolder private and don't create any setters at all.

2) Store each property inside the builder instance and create a new instance of QuestionHolder in the build method of the builder.

For example:

```
public Question<T> build() {
    // DO ALL THE VALIDATIONS NEEDED
    QuestionHolder holder = new QuestionHolder(id, order, type, inmediate, mandatory, selectedValues, possibleValues);
    return new Question<>(questionHolder);
}
```

With these approach, you will be mutating the Builder, but that's ok for the Builder Pattern. You will obviously need to create a new Builder instance each time you want to create a Question. If you want to use the same Builder over and over again you will probably need to store some kind of structure inside it (a Map identified by Id, for example).

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about thread safety, then your code here is not necessarily thread safe.

It is possible that one thread calls build() and returns a Question pointing to a QuestionHolder.  Even though build() sets the holder to null, another thread might not see that null, but instead see the old value of the field. If that other thread called any of your setters, it would potentially mutate the Holder that the Question class had already accessed.

In a single threaded application you would be fine.

Comment: normally we won't use the same Builder across different thread anyway.